# ANGULAR 2+ Removal of the component after its creation

Tags: angular

I'm dynamically creating a component, and I'd like to delete it after 1 second.

I want to do something like that

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const time = timer(2000);
    time.subscribe(() => {
       REMOVE YOURSELF / THIS COMPONENT
    });
  }
```

Comment: How are you creating your component exactly ? Please provide some code.

Comment: I want to generate them using loops

Comment: Any reason why you're not just using `ng-if`?

Comment: @Wojtar again, please provide some code. There are several ways to create dynamic components, without even counting what you consider yourself as "dynamic".

Answer (score 1):

Make a directive for `component holder` for dynamic component as below:

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: '[component-holder]',
})
export class DynamicComponentDirective {
    constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

Use `ViewChild` to import it to your component as below:

```
@ViewChild(DynamicComponentDirective ) dynamicComponentDirective : DynamicComponentDirective ;
```

After creating some dynamic component, you can remove it as below.

```
this.viewContainerRef = this.dynamicComponentDirective.viewContainerRef;
this.viewContainerRef.clear();
```